# diffie hellman encryption public key gives wrong value

Tags: java, encryption

So im trying to make a client-server diffie hellman encryption .
i use this:  `serverPublicKey = (int)Math.pow(generator,serverPrivateKey)%prime;` to generate server's public key and this : `clientPublicKey = (int)Math.pow(generator,clientPrivateKey)%prime;` to generate client's public key .

When i send the server's public key to client its all good. usually gives as a result a 2 digit integer(ex 34).
But when i send the client's public key to server every time i take large numbers like this result as : 167772160

here is my code

**SERVER SIDE**

```
int clientPublicKey;
int serverPrivateKey;
int serverPublicKey;
int prime = rand.nextInt(100); 
int generator = rand.nextInt(20);
//sending generator and prime to client
IntToClient.writeInt(prime);//1
IntToClient.writeInt(generator);//2
System.out.println("sent to client Prime :"+prime);
System.out.println("sent to client Generator :"+generator);
System.out.println("Server's private key: ");
serverPrivateKey = sc.nextInt();
//server's public key
serverPublicKey = (int)Math.pow(generator,serverPrivateKey)%prime;
System.out.println("Server sends in public --> "+ serverPublicKey);
IntToClient.writeInt(serverPublicKey);//3
clientPublicKey = IntFromClient.readInt();//4
System.out.println("Client sent public key --> "+ clientPublicKey);
```

**CLIENT SIDE**

```
int prime;
int generator;
int clientPrivateKey;
int clientPublicKey;
int serverPublicKey;

//get random prime and generator from server
prime = IntFromServer.readInt();//1
generator = IntFromServer.readInt();//2
System.out.println("Prime :"+prime);
System.out.println("Generator :"+generator);

//read server's public key
serverPublicKey = IntFromServer.readInt();//3
System.out.println("Server sent public key --> "+ serverPublicKey);

//clients private key
System.out.println("Client's private key: ");
clientPrivateKey = sc.nextInt();
//client's public key
clientPublicKey = (int)Math.pow(generator,clientPrivateKey)%prime;

System.out.println("Client sends in public --> "+ clientPublicKey);
IntToServer.writeInt(clientPublicKey);//4`
```

So when i runs it i get this from **server**

`sent to client Prime :44
sent to client Generator :3
Server's private key: 
45
Server sends in public --> 23
Client sent public key --> 167772160`

And this from **client**

`Prime :44
Generator :3
Server sent public key --> 23
Client's private key: 
87
Client sends in public --> 23`

Comment: but it worked at the first try. so what happened here. im confused.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk Ups, My mistake, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you send a value through your pipe (Socket? NamedPipe? SerialPort?):

```
IntToServer.writeInt(clientPublicKey);
```

... and the server reads another value than sent:

```
ClientFromClient.readInt();
```

... then obviously your pipe is not well implemented. All your encrpytion calculations shown are useless and not needed for solving this problem.

Comment: i use socket. but im still confused because it worked on  the first try when my server class sent the vale to client

Answer (score 1):

Even these smallish numbers are still too large to be handled without special care. `Math.pow()` should not be used anywhere. It converts operands to `double` and returns a `double` result. But `double` only has 52 bits of precision for a positive value and 3<sup>45</sup> is already a 72-bit integer.

Instead, you can do it the easy way or the hard way. The easy way is to use the [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class and its methods exclusively during your learning exercises. In particular, you want to be using [`BigInteger.modPow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow-java.math.BigInteger-java.math.BigInteger-) for all modular exponentiations.

There is a harder way. For integers this small, it is possible to implement your own modular exponentiation mod P (P is the modulus and is an `int` less than 2<sup>15.5</sup>) method. By using the [binary square-and-multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) algorithm and reducing mod P after every multiplication you can be assured that no intermediate values will overflow an `int`.

Comment: #offtopic what is it with Monica? (I see Maarten is having the same name suffic)

Comment: @gusto2: Follow the links at the top of [this](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/525/gilles-so-stop-being-evil) page.